# Debugging I/O completion threads leak

Tags: .net, threadpool, windbg

I'm trying to find a possible I/O completion threads leak in a .NET app.
From time to time I'm sampling the number of available I/O completion threads using [ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads.aspx).
At some point the number of available threads starts to degrade from 1000 to 1 (in several minutes).

I don't see any memory leak, errors, delay in execution or anything like it once it gets to 1 available thread.

In windbg, when running !threads I see ~700 threads, non of the them comes from the threadpool, most of them are marked with XXXX (as far as I know it means the GC didn't collect the thread yet), for example:
XXXX  2a4  1630 37d54610      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 004b70d8     0 Ukn (or MTA)

How can debug this one? how can I see the callstacks of the completion threads?

When running !threadpool, I get the following:

> CPU utilization: 31% Worker Thread: Total: 2047 Running: 2047 Idle: 0
> MaxLimit: 2047 MinLimit: 2 Work Request in Queue: 0
> -------------------------------------- Number of Timers: 4
> -------------------------------------- Completion Port Thread:Total: 1000 Free: 1 MaxFree: 4 CurrentLimit: 999 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 2

However,

Comment: "once it gets to 1 available thread" does not make any sense. Should it perhaps be "until it gets to 1 available thread" instead ?

Comment: What do you mean "a possible [...] leak" ?  The way you describe it, this is definitely a leak.

Comment: Run Perfmon.exe and add the ".NET CLR Memory", Gen x collection counters for your process.  Keep an eye on them to check if any garbage collections are occurring.  Seeing none is an explanation for this problem, you'll have to help.

Comment: I'm wrote "possible" since I was not sure whether it is a valid behavior of the .NET pool of allocating the entire pool in case of stress (high CPU, for example)

Answer (score 2):

Run !sos.name2ee mscorlib.dll System.Threading.Thread and make a note of the MethodTable.
Then run !sos.dumpheap -mt [MT].  This will give you a list of the thread objects.  Then run !sos.gcroot [THREADOBJ] to see what's holding on to them.

Comment: Steve, is searching the heap using the MethodTable different than searching based on type? IOW, would !sos.dumpheap -type System.Threading.Thread yield different results?

Comment: Using -type would work, but would have the unfortunate side effect of including too much, because -type uses partial string matching.  For example System.Threading.ThreadPool would be included.

Comment: Sorry for the late response; I already did what you suggest but I get only 71 managed threads. 
I'm thinking on closing this question since I'm seeing an internal exception in one of the threads and it looks like it root is the GC (corruption?) so it is possible GC was not running for a while and the heap got corrupted somehow.